# Cyclotomic Fields - Showing that the fixed field of $G(\mathbb Q(\xi)/\mathbb Q)$ is $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

If $p$ is a prime and $\xi$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity, I know that $G(\mathbb Q(\xi)/\mathbb Q) = \{\psi_{\xi,\xi^k}\}_{1\leq k<p}$, where for each $k$, $\psi_{\xi,\xi^k}(\xi) = \xi^k$. I also know that $\forall\alpha\in \mathbb Q(\xi)$, $\exists a_0,\ldots,a_{p-1}\in\mathbb Q$ such that
$$
\alpha = a_0 + a_1\xi + \cdots + a_{p-1}\xi^{p-1}.
$$
Then for each $k$, $1\leq k<p$,
$$
\psi_{\xi,\xi^k}(a_1\xi) = a_1\xi^k.
$$
This shows that if $\alpha$ is in the fixed field of $G(\mathbb Q(\xi)/\mathbb Q)$, then $a_1 = \cdots = a_{p-1}$. However, I don't know how to show that each of these coefficients is in fact $0$.

Comment: Because if $K/F$ is Galois extension then the fixed field of $G$ is precisely $F$.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki I have not yet encountered this result, since I have just started learning about Galois theory, but thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more elementary argument which avoids the use of Galois theory. You said that, you concluded that $a_1 = ... = a_{p-1}$, call this common value $a$. Therefore, 
$$ \alpha = a_0 + a(z + z^2 + ... + z^{p-1}) = a_0 + a(-1) $$
In particular, $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$.